# How to put 3 figures in one slide in beamer?

Tags: beamer

I would like to create a slide in beamer and put 3 figures inside it with some text as show in the figure below.

I tried this but it does not work.

```
\frame{\frametitle{Examples}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item[]<2-3> text 1
        \item[]<3> text 2
    \end{itemize}
    \includegraphics[height=.4\textheight,width=.4\textwidth]{fig1}
    \includegraphics[height=.4\textheight,width=.4\textwidth]{fig2}
    \includegraphics[height=.4\textheight,width=.4\textwidth]{fig3}
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility using a combination of `columns` and `minipage`s of fixed height:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-b}
\end{minipage}
\column{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
  \item Third.
  \end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[c][0.4\textheight][c]{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{minipage}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply a  ***image***`\quad`***minipage with text***`\\[1em]`***image***`\quad` ***image***?

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%   dummy text
\def\Blablabla{ 
 Some text, some text some text
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item First. \item Second. \item Third.
  \end{enumerate}
 Some text
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-a}\quad%
\begin{minipage}[b][0.4\textheight][c]{.45\linewidth} \Blablabla \end{minipage}\\[1em]
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-b}\quad%
\includegraphics[width=.45\linewidth]{example-image-c}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

While certain tweaking may be needed, the following works for me.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
  \frametitle{Use Columns to Put Elements}

  \begin{columns}[c]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
          \rule[10.0mm]{30.0mm}{10.0mm}
        \end{center}
    \end{column}
    \vrule
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{itemize}
      \item My text line one.
      \item My text line two.
      \end{itemize}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
  \hrule
  \begin{columns}[c]
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
        \begin{center}
          \rule[10.0mm]{30.0mm}{10.0mm}
        \end{center}
    \end{column}
    \vrule
    \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
      \begin{center}
        \rule[10.0mm]{30.0mm}{10.0mm}
      \end{center}
    \end{column}
  \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]