# How to insert three images in one slide?

Tags: beamer, graphics, presentations

I am having a problem with inserting three images to one slide 
There is one similar question [How to put 3 figures in one slide in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228629/how-to-put-3-figures-in-one-slide-in-beamer) 
However, this one is when one wants to put text there.

What I need is to insert three images one on top and two down with captions

I tried

```
\documentclass{beamer}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
    \centering
        \caption {example1}
        \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{example-image-a}
               \vspace{0.01em}
        \caption {example2}
        \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption {example3}
         \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=4cm]{example-image-c}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, what's the problem?

[image: slide 5cm]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \hfil\hfil\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}\newline
  \null\hfil\hfil\makebox[5cm]{example1}\newline
  \vfil
  \hfil\hfil\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-b}\hfil\hfil
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-c}\newline
  \null\hfil\hfil\makebox[5cm]{example2}
    \hfil\hfil\makebox[5cm]{example3}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    \documentclass{beamer}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
      \centering
        \begin{tabular}{c}
        example1\\
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
      \end{tabular}

      \vspace{0.01em}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
        example2  & example3 \\
        \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
         &
         \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}
         \end{tabular}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, it is better to use only `width` or `height` for `\includegraphics` so that picture is not distorted. If you use both, use `keepaspectratio` also.

Comment: this is very good but there are two problems, one I don't want to show the Figure on top of each image. second the images are pretty small and if i change the size, it messes up !!!

Comment: @Nemo See the update. For size, you can use only the available space on the slide. So use carefully.

Comment: if i use 3cm, my images are becoming so small :-(

Comment: @Nemo Yeah, you have to srop them or use the trim option of `graphicx`. See the manual.

Answer (score 1):

you can center the one on top. Below you can put the two graphics inside minipages. The code should look something like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\frame{
  \centering
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{example1}
  \includegraphics[width=5cm, height=3cm]{pic1}
  \end{figure}
  \vspace{0.01em}
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{example2}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=3cm]{pic2}
  \end{figure} 
  \end{minipage}
  %
  \hfill % fill the gap between the graphics
  %
  \begin{minipage}{0.4\textwidth}
  \begin{figure}
  \caption{example3}
  \includegraphics[width=3cm, height=3cm]{pic3}
  \end{figure}
  \end{minipage}
}
\end{document}
```

This one is working. Please post a running example next time...
btw. this page could be useful http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~frank/ENG/latex-course/latex-course-3/latex-course-3_en.html

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative approach:**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Three images in one slide}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \vspace*{-0.3cm} % remove spacing between figure and caption
  \caption{Example A}
\end{figure}
\vspace*{-1cm}
\begin{columns}[T]
  \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-b}
      \vspace*{-0.3cm}
      \caption{Example B}
    \end{figure}
  \end{column}
  \begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[width=.8\textwidth]{example-image-c}
      \vspace*{-0.3cm}
      \caption{Example C}
    \end{figure}
  \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: three images in one slide]