# Trouble putting three tables and a figure in one frame

Tags: beamer, presentations

Almost same as in [How to put 3 figures in one slide in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228629/how-to-put-3-figures-in-one-slide-in-beamer)
I am trying to put three tables and a figure in one frame. More precisely, inside a four quadrants grid.
Can you tell me how I can do so by resizing these four elements so that each element can fit a quadrant of the grid? Is there any package to use that does this automatically?

nb. Adjustbox isn't working well for me.

```
\begin{frame}
    \noindent
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[l][\dimexpr 0.300\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr .495\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}
    \begin{figure}
      \includegraphics[]{SomeFigure}
    \end{figure}
\end{minipage}%
}%
\hfill
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[r][\dimexpr 0.300\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr .495\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Blabla}       & \textbf{Blabla}             & \textbf{Blabla}          & \textbf{Blabla}          \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        555                        & 555 & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{minipage}%
}%
\vfill
\noindent
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[l][\dimexpr 0.300\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr .495\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
    \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Blabla}       & \textbf{Blabla}             & \textbf{Blabla}          & \textbf{Blabla}          \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        555                        & 555 & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{minipage}%
}%
\hfill
\fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[r][\dimexpr 0.300\textheight-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax][t]{\dimexpr .495\textwidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule\relax}%
            \begin{table}[h]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Blabla}       & \textbf{Blabla}             & \textbf{Blabla}          & \textbf{Blabla}          \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        555                        & 555 & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    \end{minipage}%
}%
\end{frame}
```

Comment: Please add a  [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your porblem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

The above shown output can be achieved using the following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}%
  \vspace{0pt}
     \centering \footnotesize
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Blabla} & \textbf{Blabla}  & \textbf{Blabla}  & \textbf{Blabla} \\
        \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  \vfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}
  \vspace{0pt}
     \centering \footnotesize
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Blabla} & \textbf{Blabla}  & \textbf{Blabla}  & \textbf{Blabla} \\
        \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.49\textwidth}%
  \vspace{0pt}
     \centering \footnotesize
     \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Blabla} & \textbf{Blabla}  & \textbf{Blabla}  & \textbf{Blabla} \\
        \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
        555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
     \end{tabular}
  \end{minipage}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: In this case, how do we add a caption to each table ?

Comment: @YellowishLight: Either enclose the `tabluar` environments in `table` environments and use the usual `\caption` command, or alternatively load the `capt-of` package and use the `\captionof{table}{...}` command in order to add captions to the tables.

Answer (score 2):

I would simply use beamers column mechanism to place the image and the tables besides each other. To squeeze the tables in the available space a smaller font size helps:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\scriptsize
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Blabla}       & \textbf{Blabla}             & \textbf{Blabla}          & \textbf{Blabla}          \\ \hline
            555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
            555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
            555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
            555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
            555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
            555                        & 555 & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\bigskip
\begin{columns}[onlytextwidth]
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Blabla}       & \textbf{Blabla}             & \textbf{Blabla}          & \textbf{Blabla}          \\ \hline
            555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
            555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
            555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
            555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
            555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
            555                        & 555 & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
      \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
            \hline
            \textbf{Blabla}       & \textbf{Blabla}             & \textbf{Blabla}          & \textbf{Blabla}          \\ \hline
            555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
            555 & 555 & 555 & 555 \\ \hline
            555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
            555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
            555                        & 555                        & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
            555                        & 555 & 555                        & 555                        \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{column}    
\end{columns}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]